# How to use Selenium ByChained in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to use Selenium's `ByChained` to create a locator that takes two or more locators. I've tried various versions of the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By, ByChained
myLocator = ByChained((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "selector_top_level"),(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "selector_bottom_level")
```

I can't for the life of me find the correct import statement. (Getting various versions of the following error:

```
has no attribute 'ByChained'
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by Does not mention ByChained however it seems to exist I just can't find where to import it from.

Comment: Perhaps it's not in the Python package, but in other language packages - the python documentation doesn't mention ByChained at all: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath